# What determines the sequence of object destruction in C++ program?

Tags: c++, oop, object

The C++ program is like this:

```
class Foo
{ 
    // something here
};

int main ()
{
     Foo f_A;
     Foo f_B;
     Foo f_C;
     //do something here

     return 0;
}
```

It has been proved that `f_A`,which constructs before `f_B`, deconstructs after `f_B`, and `f_B` deconstructs after `f_C` in g++ .What determine the sequence ? Is it compiler related ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard specifies the order.

Paragraph 6.7/2:

> Variables with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) are initialized each
>   time their declaration-statement is executed. Variables with automatic
>   storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the
>   block (6.6).

This means that the order of construction is the same as the order the variables are listed in your source above, which is important because...

Paragraph 6.6/2:

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic
>   storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are
>   destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.

Comment: "This means that the order of construction [of automatic variables] is the same as the order the variables are listed in the source" can't be correct. but u can just add a weasel word like "generally".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Not sure I get your point. I was referring specifically to the source shown above, do you think I should make that explicit?

Comment: yes, the generic reference to "source" in an apparent explanation of the standardese listed before and after, did not at all make me think of the OP's code

Answer (score 6):

It will be the reverse order of the construction. This is specified by the C++ standard.